# How can I receive e-mail every time I receive a answer?

Tags: support, answers, email

since some months ago I do not receive any e-mail from Stackexchange sites, nor that ones informing that I receive a new answer (e.g. "1 Question Has 1 Answer - Super User").

I received it normally on the past. Why not now? I miss you on my inbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to an existing question of yours, and scroll down to below the answer list:

[image]

Or, when you post a new question:

[image]

Comment: so easy... thanks